# How to remove this known missing dependency?

Tags: dependencies, 17.04

I have ubuntu 17.04

How to remove this known missing dependency?

Screenshot of the problem

[image: please check this url, it has the screenshot of the problem]

Comment: did you Google your error ?   I did and found: https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/3522

Comment: I guess you mean "install" the dependency to get rid of the error message, not "remove" the dependency?

Comment: @WillemK that's a closed issue & actually I have posted my question there also.

Comment: Please use text for terminal outputs

Comment: Could you please post text files, dialogue messages, and program output listings as text, not as images? To achieve the latter two you can either 1) select, copy & paste the dialogue text or terminal content or 2) [save the program output to a file](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814) and use that. Longer listings (the editor will tell you what's too long) should be uploaded to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and linked to in the question. Thanks.

Comment: How did you install Spyder3? It's included in the package repositories and Apt pulls in dependencies automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is how I installed -----FOLLOW EXPLICITLY------

```
sudo apt purge spyder spyder3
sudo reboot now
```

Re-open a terminal and continue-------------

```
sudo apt install python-rope python-sympy spyder
sudo apt update
sudo reboot now
```

This is how I finally got spyder to install with missing dependencies. I assume you can use `apt` to install any of the missing dependencies found in *Help > Dependencies* and look for any highlighted missing packages. Worked for me.

Comment: Why the reboots and why update *after* all the package management actions? Neither of the former two appear related to the latter.

Answer (score 0):

Install the dependency using this command

```
sudo apt install python-rope
```

You can aswell try reinstalling it so the neccessary dependencies are reinstalled aswell.

```
sudo apt purge spyder3 && sudo apt install spyder3
```

Comment: @SumeetDeshmukh As I see it, this *does* provide an answer. It's a short one, but looks perfectly valid and to the point to me. Please recheck your review.

Comment: @ByteCommander deleted it, is that okay?

Comment: Sorry, didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Try reinstalling the software like I mention in my answer. Since I tried installing it on a fresh system and it worked without issues.